# Java Android Post JSON data

Tags: java, android, json

Hi there I'm trying to take data from EditText and post it as JSON object but it returns empty object with no data 
the object returned with only the keys and not mapped to the entered values in the EditText as shown in the screen
Note: I just need to retrive the JSON object in the Toast

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText userName;
    EditText password;
    EditText email;
    EditText phone;
    Button submit;

    Person person;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        person = new Person();

        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        person.setUserName(userName.getText().toString());

        person.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

        person.setEmail(email.getText().toString());

        person.setPhone(phone.getText().toString());
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new JsonDataConverter().execute(person);
            }
        });
    }
    private class JsonDataConverter extends AsyncTask < Person,
    Void,
    String > {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Person...params) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("userName", person.getUserName());
                jsonObject.put("password", person.getPassword());
                jsonObject.put("email", person.getEmail());
                jsonObject.put("phone", person.getPhone());
                return jsonObject.toString();
            } catch(JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonUser = new JSONObject(s);
                jsonUser.get("userName");
                jsonUser.get("password");
                jsonUser.get("email");
                jsonUser.get("phone");

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonUser.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch(JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    String userName;
    String password;
    String email;
    String phone;

    public Person() {}

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}
```

[Screen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrgwM.png)

Comment: there is no post code, you are just creating a json , adding value in `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` just fetching the value from same json without saving it anywhere

Comment: Pavneet Singh - I just need the JsonObject to be showed in the Toast with the data till know but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your were just using the Setters at wrong place. Use it in ClickListener as follows..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


person = new Person();

userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       person.setUserName(userName.getText().toString());

       person.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

       person.setEmail(email.getText().toString());

       person.setPhone(phone.getText().toString());

        new JsonDataConverter().execute(person);
    }
 });
}
```

**Edit:**
You're using higher class member person not param[0]

Comment: Although, you can use person, but you should remove person from class level and use param to access it.